# PHP form appears below again after submitting

Tags: php

I've a enrollment form enroll.php which submits to itself and if all input valid it includes confirm.php, I've to save data into tables.

looks something like this -

enroll.php

```
  <?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    include('validate.php');

    if($valid) {
        require_once ('getDBconnection.php');        
        include ('confirm.php'); 
    }
}
function test_input($data) {
         $data = trim($data);
         $data = stripslashes($data);
         $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
         return $data;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
// all html code with banner and navigation and form elements.
```

so when i get confirmation of enrollment below whole page after confirmation text , i see my form with all banner and navigation and all div contents and form.

Is it because I'm including confirm.php?

Please let me know if anything is wrong I've just started learning php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add exit after indlude confirm.php to stop executing whole site with menu etc.

```
if($valid) {
    require_once ('getDBconnection.php');        
    include ('confirm.php'); 
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect to confirm.php, not include it

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    include('validate.php');

    if($valid) {
        header('Location: confirm.php'); 
    }
}
function test_input($data) {
         $data = trim($data);
         $data = stripslashes($data);
         $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
         return $data;
    }
?>



<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
// all html code with banner and navigation and form elements.
```

#### Edit

Of course this will only work as long as you haven't output anything to the browser yet (IE: `echo 'Please fill out the form correctly';`)

Comment: Yes I tried that, it works but then I've to use session, is that the only way redirecting, isn't there way to include it and take care of this

Comment: Sure, there are several ways to skin a cat. Include exit(); after including common.php or put a test to determine if you should show the form or the confirmation text.

Answer (score 0):

Its because `enroll.php` runs to the end of the file regardless if confirm.php is included or not.

You should most likly submit the form to confirm.php, and then redirect the user in confirm.php

Answer (score 0):

You can either redirect the page to confirm.php or If you want to include confirm.php
than you need to put exit() or die() after the line include ('confirm.php');

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    include('validate.php');

    if($valid) {
        require_once ('getDBconnection.php');        
        include ('confirm.php'); 
        exit(); //or you can also use die();
    }
}
function test_input($data) {
         $data = trim($data);
         $data = stripslashes($data);
         $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
         return $data;
    }
?>
```